# Canvas LMS - Theme Editor Logos Are Not Changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, canvas-lms

I've installed Canvas LMS using

https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start

But i'm facing a problem, the logos are not changing there on Theme Editor.

But the colors are changing.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7yG1.png)

If any one have any idea , why i'ts not happening please tell me.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually i'm having a file uploading problem too, cause whenever i'm uploading some file it shows uploaded, but cant see or download. And the url goes to "https://canvas.example.com/files/8/download?download_frd=1&sf_verifier=d1fabbd476c9aac38491a8fe1503303d&ts=1513068670&user_id=1"

Comment: Please start a delayed job with help of this command 
/etc/init.d/canvas_init restart